# How to get the base package install location on Linux?

Tags: service, centos, package, rpm

I am on Linux Centos OS. I understand that using "rpm -qa" gives a lot of install paths for the corresponding package. However, I need just the base package install location for the package. Is there any way/command/option in Linux to retrieve the same? My code snippet is to retrieve list of running services and the corresponding package installed is as below:-

for i in $(service --status-all | grep -v "not running" | grep -E running\|stopped |  awk '{print $1}');
do
packagename=$(rpm -qf /etc/init.d/$i)
servicestatus=$(service --status-all | grep $i | awk '{print $NF}' | sed 's/...//g' | sed 's/.//g');

echo $tdydate, $(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk 'NR==1 {print $NF}'), $i, $packagename, $servicestatus > "$HOME/MyLog/running_services.csv"
done

Now, I need to also get the corresponding package install location as well which is hosting the running service. Is there a way to retrieve this as well along with getting the package names. Please confirm.

Thanks in advance for extending help.

Regards.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by _base package install location_? RPMs install things all over the place, depending on what they contain. Unless you tell the package manager (yum, rpm) to use a different location, all RPM installations will be relative to ``/``. It's not clear to me what it is you want to figure out.

Comment: Hi, basically what i need is:- I get a list of all installed services on my Centos using service --status-all. Now, for each service, I need to know the corresponding application package location on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, with your answer to my question in the comments, which is much clearer to me than you initial question...

> Hi, basically what i need is:- I get a list of all installed services on my Centos using service --status-all. Now, for each service, I need to know the corresponding application package location on linux.

...I'll propose this (tested here on CentOS 6.6):

`` #!/bin/bash
 for i in `chkconfig --list | awk '{ print $1}'`; do 
    service $i status >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $?==0 ]; then 
       rpm -qf /etc/init.d/$i
    fi
 done | sort | uniq ``

That spits out all rpm names of the services which are currently running.

A bit more detail as to why your current approach is not going to work:
`service --status-all` is not going to return information which can be parsed reliably. For example, the output on a VM here:

`acpid (pid  872) is running...
auditd (pid  789) is running...
Stopped
cgred is stopped
Checking for service cloud-init:Checking for service cloud-init:Checking for service cloud-init:Checking for service cloud-init:crond (pid  1088) is running...
ip6tables: Firewall is not running.
iptables: Firewall is not running.
Kdump is not operational
mdmonitor is stopped
netconsole module not loaded
Configured devices:
lo eth0
Currently active devices:
lo eth0
ntpd (pid  997) is running...
master (pid  1076) is running...
rdisc is stopped
restorecond is stopped
rsyslogd (pid  809) is running...
sandbox is stopped
saslauthd is stopped
openssh-daemon (pid  988) is running...`

Some services don't even return their name (third line). Some say `stopped`, others `not running`. If you parse the first column of `chkconfig --list` you know all the service names, which correspond to files in `/etc/init.d`. Then you can query their status individually and read the *return code* (`$?`), which is 0 for running services (or generally for success in the Unix/Linux world), 1 or higher for not running or not installed or incomplete/malfunctioning services.

Armed with names in `/etc/init.d/` you can then query the owning package with `rpm -qf /etc/init.d/<servicename>` and get exactly what I think you were looking for.

Edit: added `| sort | uniq` after the loop, because some packages contain multiple services, like for example cloud-init, which creates four different services on CentOS. So you sort the list, then make sure you only get distinct (uniq) names back.
Works for me:

`acpid-1.0.10-2.1.el6.x86_64
audit-2.3.7-5.el6.x86_64
cloud-init-0.7.5-10.el6.centos.2.x86_64
cronie-1.4.4-12.el6.x86_64
cyrus-sasl-2.1.23-15.el6_6.1.x86_64
initscripts-9.03.46-1.el6.centos.1.x86_64
iptables-1.4.7-14.el6.x86_64
iptables-ipv6-1.4.7-14.el6.x86_64
iputils-20071127-17.el6_4.2.x86_64
kexec-tools-2.0.0-280.el6.x86_64
libcgroup-0.40.rc1-15.el6_6.x86_64
mdadm-3.3-6.el6.x86_64
ntp-4.2.6p5-1.el6.centos.x86_64
ntpdate-4.2.6p5-1.el6.centos.x86_64
openssh-server-5.3p1-104.el6_6.1.x86_64
policycoreutils-2.0.83-19.47.el6_6.1.x86_64
postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_5.x86_64
rsyslog-5.8.10-9.el6_6.x86_64
udev-147-2.57.el6.x86_64`

Comment: Thanks mate for the revert. However, below output got me confused. Service is shown as not running and the status code is '0'. How is that possible? The problem is, when I try to fetch service status using return code from service "service name" status, it returns all "0" i.e. running while we have services which are stopped.

[root@rt vbatra]# service radiusd status radiusd is stopped [root@rt vbatra]# service radiusd status | echo $? 0 [root@rt vbatra]#

Any idea whats wrong here?

Comment: @vipinbatra don't pipe into echo. That'll always be successful, unless you really find something that echo cannot print. :)   try ``service radiusd status ; echo $?`` (with semicolon instead of pipe). If that doesn't work, you'd have to have a look at /etc/init.d/radiusd and see why it doesn't return 0. Just compare it with something that reports the correct value. Most init scripts have an almost identical structure, so should be easy to spot the problem.

Comment: Thanks mate for the quick revert. I will give this a try. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `--whatprovides` instead of `-qf` (which does formatting).

Tweaking your example...

`for i in $(chkconfig --list | awk '{ print $1}'); do service $i status >/dev/null 2>&1; if [ 0==$? ]; then echo -n "$i: "; rpm -q --whatprovides /etc/init.d/$i; fi; done | sort`

FYI - this doesn't work on more modern `systemd`-based systems (CentOS 7).

Example on my Fedora 21 box:

```
Note: This output shows SysV services only and does not include native
      systemd services. SysV configuration data might be overridden by native
      systemd configuration.

      If you want to list systemd services use 'systemctl list-unit-files'.
      To see services enabled on particular target use
      'systemctl list-dependencies [target]'.

netconsole: initscripts-9.56.1-5.fc21.x86_64
network: initscripts-9.56.1-5.fc21.x86_64
```

Comment: I'm one of those people who can't leave things alone. A quick-and-dirty `systemd` version:
`systemctl list-dependencies default.target --plain | egrep \\.service | cut -c3- | xargs -IXXX rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/lib/systemd/system/XXX 2>/dev/null | sort -u`